# How Do I get an HOC wrapped component function from enzyme instance when mounting?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have parent -> child components, and the child runs fetch inside `componentDidMount`. The fetch sets state in a redux store that is above parent, and that causes child component to display differently.

The child is also using `material-ui` `withStyles`, so it creates an HOC around the component.

In my test, I need to mount the parent component, find the child component, and then see that the fetch has correctly changed state and caused the child to update.

My solution so far is this:

- mount parent, find child
- call `child.instance().fetchFunction().then(() => expect(..))`

However, calling `instance()` on `child` returns the HOC, and so I get the error:

> child.instance(...).fetchFunction is not a function

All solutions I have seen use `shallow` and `dive` to get around the HOC, but if I use `shallow` I will have to create a mock store in the test, and it won't actually test this as an integration test.

I could test the individual fetch call, and then test the component using `shallow` and pass it the props as if the state were changed, but that doesn't prove that it all works together.

Here is a codesandbox where I have reproduced the issue:

[image: Edit Testing Async componentDidMount]

Here is some example code (basically the codesandbox):

`App.js`

```
import React from "react";
import Child from "./Child";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Child />;
  }
}

export default App;
```

`Child.js`

```
import React from "react";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const childStyles = {
  margin: 0
};

class Child extends React.Component {
  state = {
    groceries: [],
    errorStatus: ""
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("calling fetch");

    this.fetchCall();
  }

  fetchCall = () => {
    return fetch("/api/v1/groceries")
      .then(this.checkStatus)
      .then(this.parseJSON)
      .then(this.setStateFromData)
      .catch(this.setError);
  };

  checkStatus = results => {
    if (results.status >= 400) {
      console.log("bad status");

      throw new Error("Bad Status");
    }

    return results;
  };

  setError = () => {
    console.log("error thrown");

    return this.setState({ errorStatus: "Error fetching groceries" });
  };

  parseJSON = results => {
    console.log("parse json");

    return results.json();
  };

  setStateFromData = data => {
    console.log("setting state");

    return this.setState({ groceries: data.groceries });
  };

  render() {
    const { groceries } = this.state;

    return (
      <div id="app">
        {groceries.map(grocery => {
          return <div key={grocery.id}>{grocery.item}</div>;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(childStyles)(Child);
```

`App.test.js`

```
import Enzyme from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
import React from "react";
import { mount } from "enzyme";
import App from "./App";
import Child from "./Child";

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

const mockResponse = (status, statusText, response) => {
  return new window.Response(response, {
    status: status,
    statusText: statusText,
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json"
    }
  });
};

describe("App", () => {
  describe("ChildApp componentDidMount", () => {
    it("sets the state componentDidMount", () => {
      console.log("starting test for 200");

      global.fetch = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() =>
        Promise.resolve(
          mockResponse(
            200,
            null,
            JSON.stringify({
              groceries: [{ item: "nuts", id: 10 }, { item: "greens", id: 3 }]
            })
          )
        )
      );

      const renderedComponent = mount(<App />);
      const childApp = renderedComponent.find(Child);

      childApp
        .instance()
        .fetchCall()
        .then(() => {
          console.log("finished test for 200");
          expect(childApp.state("groceries").length).toEqual(2);
        });
    });

    it("sets the state componentDidMount on error", () => {
      console.log("starting test for 500");

      window.fetch = jest
        .fn()
        .mockImplementation(() =>
          Promise.resolve(
            mockResponse(
              400,
              "Test Error",
              JSON.stringify({ status: 400, statusText: "Test Error!" })
            )
          )
        );

      const renderedComponent = mount(<App />);
      const childApp = renderedComponent.find(Child);
      childApp
        .instance()
        .fetchCall()
        .then(() => {
          console.log("finished test for 500");
          expect(childApp.state("errorStatus")).toEqual(
            "Error fetching groceries"
          );
        });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: There's a problem is in testing methodology. *it won't actually test this end-to-end, like I want ... call child.instance().fetchFunction().then(() => expect(..))* - this is not e2e test but some sort of inefficient integration test. You're still testing child unit directly but doing this in a way that can hardly be justified. There's nothing that requires Child to be tested as a part of App test. Any way, you can get a reference to a component inside withStyles HOC with `innerRef`, https://material-ui.com/customization/css-in-js/#withstyles-styles-options-higher-order-component

Comment: You are right, it's not e2e, I have changed it to read "integration test". I have tried using `instance().innerRef` but it returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After writing this up, I found the answer, but I feel like this is worth sharing because I was very confused about it.

Instead of using `app.find(Child)` (component constructor), use `app.find('Child')` (component display name). This will find the actual component and not the hoc-wrapped component.

[enzyme docs for find(selector)](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/find.html)